# Getting error @wdio/cli:launcher with missing capabilities in Visual Studio Code WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io, vscode-debugger

When I am running debugger in Visual Studio Code, I get the following:

`ERROR @wdio/cli:launcher missing capabilities, exiting with failure`